# resolution issues with my ipython map (matplotlib)

Tags: python, arrays

Ive been working with python, Im quite new with all this language. ive been trying to make a list become and array and then to give me on each row the highest value.

Now this information comes from a txt, so far what I have is the following:

```
import re
from numpy import *
filesis= open("/home/ana/Escritorio/Python/CATALOGO_NIC_MW (otra copia).txt")
filelines= filesis.readlines()
magn1, magn2, magn3= [],[], [], []



for reader in filelines:        
    mag1=(((re.sub(r'[^0-9|.]', r'.00', (reader[56:59]))))) 
    magn1=(mag1[0:3])
    #****************************************************
    mag2=(((re.sub(r'[^0-9|.]', r'.00 ', (reader[64:67])))))
    magn2=(mag2[0:3])
    #****************************************************
    mag3=(((re.sub(r'[^0-9|.]', r'.00 ', (reader[72:75])))))
    magn3=(mag3[0:3])
    #****************************************************
    for index in range(len(magnitud1)):
        magnitudes.append([magnitud1[index],magnitud2[index],magnitud3[index]])
        print magnitudes
```

But my output is the following:

```
    [['5', '6', '6']]
    [['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.']]
    [['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1']]
    [['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6']]
    [['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.']]
    [['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.',     '.'],['5', '1', '1']]
[['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6']]
[['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.']]
[['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1']]
[['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['6', '6', '6']]
[['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['6', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.']]
[['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['5', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '1', '1'], ['6', '6', '6'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['5', '8', '8']]
```

Sorry for the long post but I wanted to show you how it looks.

```
1522  0 0  0 0  0.00   11.830 -86.980   5.0 NIC  0     5.5SCAL 6.1WCAL 6.1WXXX1
1524  0 0  0 0  0.00   11.950 -86.150   5.0 NIC  0     5.5SCAL 6.1WCAL 6.1WXXX1
1527  0 0  0 0  0.00   12.600 -86.860   5.0 NIC  0     5.5SCAL 6.1WCAL 6.1WXXX1
1528  5 0  0 0  0.00   12.400 -86.800  33.0 NIC  0     6.5SCAL 6.8WCAL 6.8WXXX1


5.5SCAL 6.1WCAL 6.1WXXX1
5.5SCAL 6.1WCAL 6.1WXXX1
5.5SCAL 6.1WCAL 6.1WXXX1
6.5SCAL 6.8WCAL 6.8WXXX1
```

The information is coming out of the text file above and then below you will see that the last three rows is my information source.

```
magnitude=[[5.5],[6.1],[6.1]]
           [5.5],[6.1],[6.1]
           [5.5],[6.1],[6.1]
           [6.5],[6.8],[6.8]]

magnitude=[[6.1]]
           [6.1]
           [6.1]
           [6.8]]
```

What Im looking to have an array like `magnitude` and then get the highest value of every row of the array as shown above.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your source looks like a TSV (tab separated values) or a text file using fixed-width columns. If it is a TSV, Look at the `csv` module. If it is using a fixed-width text format, just iterate over the file and use string slices to get the values you want. I don't know why you are using regular expressions for, but I guess you are using the wrong one.

When you manage to get a 2d array out of the file, the builtin function `max` will return the biggest item from an iterable.

```
>>> max([[5.5],[6.1],[6.1]])
[6.1]
```

So you can do:

```
>>> [max(line) for line in magnitude]
```